# Datagridview1 does not include new database rows

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

I am porting a program from VS C# 2003 to VS C# 2012 and am encountering a problem in 2012 that I did not run into when using C# 2003.

To demonstrate, I created a simple form1 with only a single `datagridview1`.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

//includes only this
this.table1TableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Table1);
```

and datagridview1 correctly displays the 2 test rows in the datasource (MS Access dB)

The problem is, if I add a 3rd row to the MS Access dB and run the program again, 
it still only shows the original 2 rows.

I have searched repeatedly for a solution so the `datagridview1` will show new dB rows, starting with row 3, but cannot find it. This should not be this hard, should it?!

This link appeared to have the solution: 
[how to update rows list of a datagridview after adding new row to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259251/how-to-update-rows-list-of-a-datagridview-after-adding-new-row-to-a-table)

but I cannot get it to work.

Help!

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "run the program again"? Did you hit a button on the window or did you run it from desktop/explorer? Also, please show and check your select. Maybe the new row you have added does not meet the SELECT criteria.

Answer (score 0):

As you meantined in this [SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259251/how-to-update-rows-list-of-a-datagridview-after-adding-new-row-to-a-table) try to set the dataGridView's DataSource to null and then bind it again.

I would suggest to use a `void` for that and calling it whenever you want.

add `using System.Data.OleDb`

Example

```
private void LoadData()
{
string Constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/PathToYourAccessFile";
string SQLstr = "Select * from YourAccessTable";
OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(Constr);
Conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter ODA;
DataTable DT;
ODA = new OleDbDataAdapter (SQLstr, Conn ); 
DT = new DataTable();
ODA.Fill(DT);
dataGridView1.DataSource = DT ;
Conn.Close();

}
```

call the method like `LoadData();`

This is way to directly access the `Access` database

```
    NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.RegionTableAdapter regionTableAdapter = 
        new NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.RegionTableAdapter();

regionTableAdapter.Delete(5, "NorthWestern");
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171935.aspx)

From Inserting directly from `WinForms` try following

```
 string myConnectionString;
        myConnectionString =
                @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                @"Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;";

        using (var con = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
            con.Open();

            using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText =
                    @"INSERT INTO YourTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES ('Hello', 'World')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Use this code to open the database in datagridview

Comment: No, it did not. How come I cannot hit carriage return to go to the next line here? Oh well! I did this: this.table1TableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Table1); LoadData(); and private void LoadData() was as you showed. Now the datagrid has no rows, not even the 2 original rows.

Comment: If I added this:                                                    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadData(); 
        }                                                            the result was the same. I don't understand why a table1tableadapter.fill would not be dynamic by default and not automatically get new dB rows? I've tried to track this problem down for over a week.

Comment: That worked!!! Thanks! Before it would run I needed to add using System.Data.OleDb ; then drop 'static' from static string Constr (else got "the modifier 'static' is not valid for this item") and change the path to this --> Data Source=C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\Database1.accdb" then it worked!! Way cool. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user3260976 Glad to help, you might accept this as an answer if it was solution to your problem.

Comment: I tried to Answer but got this: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking You can answer 2/2/2014 1:51:09 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead. I'll update tomorrow.

Comment: @user3260976 if my answer worked for you, please mark it as an answer so it would help other with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by adding LoadData to Form1_Load, like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.table1TableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Table1);
        LoadData(); 

    }
```

where LoadData is per Marek's suggestion:

```
    private void LoadData()
    {
        string Constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\Database1.accdb";
        string SQLstr = "Select * from Table1";
        OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(Constr);
        Conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter ODA;
        DataTable DT;
        ODA = new OleDbDataAdapter (SQLstr, Conn ); 
        DT = new DataTable();
        ODA.Fill(DT);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DT ;
        Conn.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Why did you posted same answer as I posted? To let the community know about the right answer use the button "Mark as an answer" on the left side of the post.